# Search Multiple Attributes in Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, search, leaflet, geojson

I have a Leaflet map containing a GeojSON layer with 4 Attributes. I added 4 search functions to filter these attributes separately but now i need a search function where user enters four attributes and does a combined query. Some thing like AND operation. How can i modify my code to search multiple attributes ?

Here's the snippet from my code:

```
map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
        layer: Points,        
        propertyName: 'Road Name',
        textPlaceholder:'Search by Road Name',
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) { console.log(latlng); map.setView(latlng, 16); }
        }));


        map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
        layer: Points,        
        propertyName: 'Subcategor',
        textPlaceholder:'Search by Subcategory',
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) { console.log(latlng); map.setView(latlng, 16); }
        }));


        map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
        layer: Points,        
        propertyName: 'Status',
        textPlaceholder:'Search by Status',

        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) { console.log(latlng); map.setView(latlng, 16); }
        }));


        map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
        layer: Points,        
        propertyName: 'Date Detec',
        textPlaceholder:'Search by Date',
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) { console.log(latlng); map.setView(latlng, 16); }
        }));
```

[Popup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtYD0.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple solution for you problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dbcy3vp0/

It mainly uses the filterData cb to 'connect' multiple searches.

Just enter "123" and "foo" in the search bars and see what's happening.

```
var controlFound1 = false, controlFound2 = false;

  var controlFunction = function()     
            {
        if(controlFound1 && controlFound2)         document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "found"
        else
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "not found"
        };

    map.addLayer(markersLayer);
    var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
    propertyName:"bar",
        position:'topright',        
        layer: markersLayer,
        zoom: 15,
    moveToLocation:controlFunction,
    filterData:function(a,b) {   
        if(Object.keys(b).indexOf(a)>-1) controlFound1 = true;
      else controlFound1 = false;
    }
    });
  var controlSearch2 = new L.Control.Search({
    propertyName:"title",
        position:'topright',        
        layer: markersLayer,
        zoom: 15,
    moveToLocation:controlFunction,
    filterData:function(a,b) {   
        if(Object.keys(b).indexOf(a)>-1) controlFound2 = true;
      else controlFound2 = false;
    }
    });
    map.addControl( controlSearch );
  map.addControl( controlSearch2 );

  var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09],{title:"foo",bar:"123"}).addTo(markersLayer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I tried adding the same function to my code for "Road Name" and "Subcategor" Fields but i get an error when i search "Location not found" .  `var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
   propertyName:"Road Name",
    
  layer: Points,
  zoom: 15,
    moveToLocation:controlFunction,
    filterData:function(a,b) {   
     if(Object.keys(b).indexOf(a)>-1) controlFound1 = true;
      else controlFound1 = false;
    }
 });
  var controlSearch2 = new L.Control.Search({
   propertyName:"Subcategor",
   zoom: 15, 
  layer: Points,`

Comment: Then are you sure that you have the properties ("Road Name", "Subcategor") in the marker? You didn't show where you add the marker. See `var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09],{title:"foo",bar:"123"}).addTo(markersLayer)` Can you show, how "Points" looks like?

Comment: Points is geoJSON data with "Road Name" and "Subcategor" Fields in its attribute table. It works fine and attributes show up in popups .  `var Points = new L.geoJson(json_Data_0, {
            onEachFeature: function pop_Data_0(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table . . . </table>';
 layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
        } }); map.addLayer(Points);`

Comment: Whats the output of `filterData:function(a,b) {  console.log(a,b);  }` Is it as expected?

Comment: I think the problem here is that Points is not a L.LayerGroup. `var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();` From the leaflet-search documentation: _layer where search markers(is a L.LayerGroup)_

Comment: Thanks for helping me. `filterData:function(a,b) { console.log(a,b); }`  gives me the same result. I even tried on a simpler map

Comment: According to the documentation no. But you easily can convert your geoJson object to a LayerGroup? Just iterate through your marker points and add them to a LayerGroup.

Comment: `var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();
    map.addLayer(Points);
       markersLayer.addLayer(Points);`   Still getting the same error " Location not found"

Comment: I updated the example: http://jsfiddle.net/pucfhz3d/ - hope that's clear.